# validation on import from Excel to Database using ADO.net

Tags: c#, excel, ado.net

I need to Append data from Excel to Database so I need to check for validation in Excel columns like if `dr[0]` is number or not and if any row in Excel is repeated in the database skip it and add only new records:

```
MaamoonKhalidIssueEntities db = new MaamoonKhalidIssueEntities();
                    foreach (DataTable table in result.Tables)
                    {
                        foreach (DataRow dr in table.Rows)
                        {
                            Person addtable = new Person()
                            {

                                nparent =Convert.ToInt32(dr[0]),
                                ncode = Convert.ToString(dr[1]),
                                nname = Convert.ToString(dr[2])

                            };
                        db.People.Add(addtable);
                        }
```

I Can't check on `dr[0]` because its object

Comment: You can write some simple Validation-Code. If you have a key, both in the DB and in your excel, you can first populate a new Person from Excel and after that you can compare the keys...?

Comment: I am already adding a new person  `Person addtable = new Person()` I want to check if code and the name and parent is already in the database or not

Comment: What is name, what is parent? Keep in mind, that you are the only person who know whats happening. I can only see what you´ve provided (dr[0])... You should check if the person is existent before you add the person to the database. Therefore you should have some unique-identifier to identify an entity accurately..

Comment: parent is code , where i should check before `foreach (DataRow dr in table.Rows)` or `nparent =Convert.ToInt32(dr[0])` and how can i check the data in database

Comment: How do you distinguish between two Persons? What is your key?

Comment: `ncode` should be uniqe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write a ValidateNewPerson-Method. This method tries to fetch a person with the same ncode from the DB. If this succeeds, the record is not valid, if not, the person can be added:

```
public bool ValidateNewPerson(Person newPerson, MaamoonKhalidIssueEntities db)
{
    var dbPerson = db.People.Where(e => e.ncode == newPerson.ncode).FirstOrDefault();
    if (dbPerson == null)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

Now you can call this method in your foreach:

```
foreach (DataRow dr in table.Rows)
{
    Person addtable = new Person()
    {
        nparent =Convert.ToInt32(dr[0]),
        ncode = Convert.ToString(dr[1]),
        nname = Convert.ToString(dr[2])
    };
    if (ValidateNewPerson(addtable, db))
        db.People.Add(addtable);
 }
```

If you want to use a Linq-Method, you can use Any, to request if any record in your db matches your criteria:

```
foreach (DataRow dr in table.Rows)
{
    Person addtable = new Person()
    {
        nparent =Convert.ToInt32(dr[0]),
        ncode = Convert.ToString(dr[1]),
        nname = Convert.ToString(dr[2])
    };
    if (!db.People.Any(p => p.ncode == addtable.ncode))
        db.People.Add(addtable);
 }
```

Comment: in `if (dbPerson == null)` there is notice showed to me ** the result of the expression is always 'false' since a value of type bool is never equal to 'null' of the type of 'bool'

Comment: you mus use the whole expression: var dbPerson = db.People.Select(e => e.ncode == newPerson.ncode).FirstOrDefault();

Comment: Select has bool as a return value, FirstOrDefault either null or the expected entity

Comment: i am using the all method the same notice

Comment: I´ve edited my answer. Please edit your code as well. All want make sense, because you ask, if ALL entities in your table match your condition. You can use any instead, I´ll show you in my answer...

Comment: the error in `select`  it must be `where` not `select` and it work thanks ,edit it  and i will select it as answer

Comment: Sorry.. You are totally right with the Select-thing... Don´t even know why I took select.. Glad that it works now :) Thanks for accepting !